# Cómo interpreta el Maximum Keyframe Interval de la codificación de un video la función seek de un elemento de video HTML5 en JavaScript

Tags: javascript, html5, canvas, video

Esta es una pregunta muy específica sobre el modo en que la función `seek` (de un elemento de video en **HTML5**) interpreta un video, en este caso uno en formato **WEBM** y qué relación en concreto tiene con el intervalo de cuadros clave en el proceso de codificación de dicho video.

Para entender de qué se trata esto y cómo interpreta HTML5+JavaScript el [grupo de imágenes](https://es.wikipedia.org/wiki/Group_of_pictures) (GOP) de un video con la función `seek` creé este [fiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/lengua/qo47b26h/).

> **[VER FIDDLE](https://jsfiddle.net/lengua/qo47b26h/)**

1. *Qué hace*: La idea es controlar la posición de un video en pausa con la rueda de scroll del mouse... además cada cuadro del video se copia a un elemento canvas, pero creo que eso no tiene relación. Lo menciono por si acaso.
2. *Qué mirar*: En *Chrome* (v66) y un poco menos en *Firefox* (v59) se ve bastante bien el desplazamiento cuando el video está codificado con un *Maximum Keyframe Interval* de **6** o menos, pero se aprecian saltos cuando el intervalo es de cada **24** cuadros o más. Esto se nota en el video y aún más en el canvas.
3. *FFMPEG*: Al codificar un video con *[FFMPEG](https://ffmpeg.org)* esto se consigue con la opción `-g 6` ó `-g24` de Maximum Keyframe Interval. Sin embargo el archivo resulta más pesado conforme disminuímos el intervalo. Se puede apreciar que no hay diferencia entre ambos formatos cuando el video está en `play`.

**Se puede switchear el video en el snippet con los botones.**

> **Caso 1**: Cuando usamos el video codificado con `-g 6` el desplazamiento del video es aceptable pero aumenta el tamaño: *6.229 Mb*.
>
> Cadena FFMPEG utilizada:
>
> `ffmpeg -i INPUT.MOV -c:v libvpx -qmin 0 -deadline best -qmax 50 -crf 1 -b:v 100K -g 6 test/video_g6.webm`
>
> **Caso 2**: Cuando usamos el video codificado con `-g 24` el desplazamiento no es suave y sufre de saltos pero disminuye el tamaño: *4.477 Mb*.
>
> Cadena FFMPEG utilizada:
>
> `ffmpeg -i INPUT.MOV -c:v libvpx -qmin 0 -deadline best -qmax 50 -crf 1 -b:v 100K -g 24 test/video_g24.webm`

**¿Por qué sucede esto?**

¿Qué pasa con `-keyint_min` o `-force_key_frames`? ¿Tienen algún efecto positivo? ¿Es mejor usar algo como `cgop` (closed gop)?

Agradecería alguna referencia de consulta sobre este tema o una explicación más o menos detallada de esta relación tanto para el contenedor WEBM como para MP4 y OGG video.

No estoy buscando tanto una cadena mágica de *ffmpeg* (aunque la agradecería) sino más bien una explicación de cómo funciona esta relación entre las `keyframes` y el `seek` de un video en *javascript*.

Muchas gracias por leer hasta acá.

P.D. Una cosa más, si la función `seek` sólo se detiene en un `keyframe`, ¿es posible que este cuadro tenga más calidad que los otros de forma tal que aumenta la calidad cuando se detiene el video?

**ACTUALIZACION**

No he resuelto el asunto en específico pero se puede ver ya una demo en línea con el resultado, si se resuelve esta pregunta, los tiempos de carga (el tamaño de los clips de video) se podrían reducir muchísimo (en teoría).

[OficiosCreativos.mx](https://oficioscreativos.mx)

**Nota:** Requiere Chrome en computadora de escritorio con mouse con rueda de scroll.

Answer (score 1):

No conozco el uso de ffmpeg pero el tema de los saltos se produce por la forma en que funcionan los métodos de compresión de video.

Los keyframes tienen información completa sobre lo que se muestra mientras que los demás frames unicamente tienen la variación con respecto al frame anterior.

De esto se pueden deducir dos cosas que sirven de respuesta a tu pregunta:

- A mayor cantidad de keyframes, mayor tamaño del archivo. Si tenés un video con 100 frames, con un keyframe cada 6, tenés 16 frames en total con toda la información a mostrar y 84 con variaciones. Si tuviera un keyframe cada 24, tenés únicamente 4 frames con la información completa y 96 con variaciones. Como lo más común es que los cambios no afecten todo el frame, estos son más chicos que los keyframes produciendo la variación de tamaño.
- Al tener que mostrar un frame que no es un keyframe, es necesario leer primero el keyframe y los sucesivos frames hasta llegar a "armar" el frame a partir de la información anterior. Con un keyframe cada 6 eso implica que como máximo tendríamos que recorrer 5 frames para armar la imagen a mostrar, mientras que un keyframe cada 24 esa cantidad se eleva a 23. El aumento de frames posibles a recorrer es lo que produce que el tiempo de procesamiento sea mayor y se produzcan los saltos.

Comment: ¿Alguna referencia? ¿Qué datos se capturan en el KeyFrame? ¿qué relación hay con la función `seek`?

Comment: Como referencia te cito el mismo artículo que linkeaste sobre GOP. Los keyframes son las imágenes tipo I, mientras que los otros dos constituyen el resto de los frames. Con respecto a la implementación propiamente dicha, depende del codec. En los respectivos artículos de la Wikipedia vas a poder encontrar más información sobre cada uno. Con respecto a la función seek que mencionas ni es parte del estándar HTML5, ni aparece en tu ejemplo por lo que no sabría darte más información...

Comment: Claro que se usa `seek` es en código. Lo siento, pero tu respuesta no me dice nada que no supiera ya.

Comment: No pasa nada... Si no te ayuda en nada te debo haber entendido mal... Te recomiendo que si el **¿Por qué sucede esto?** no es la pregunta que quieres hacer no lo pongas destacado y con signos de pregunta porque confunde. Saludos!